# Certain Apple Magic Keyboard key chords not working

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a wireless  Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad. The keyboard is mostly working correctly, but a number of key chords involving the left command key do not work.

I'm pretty sure this is a hardware problem but want to get advice before I replace the keyboard.

Any ideas? Or is it time to upgrade this keyboard to one of those cool new colorful keyboards with big bold clunky keys?

**Symptoms**

The keyboard is working just fine, except that the following key combinations are completely ignored:

- Left-Command + Shift + "}"
- Left-Command + "}"
- Left-Command + Return
- Left-Command + Shift + "+"

Yet these work fine:

- Left-Command + Shift + "{"
- Left-Command + "{"
- Left-Command + "-"
- Right-Command + Shift + "}"
- Right-Command + "}"
- Right-Command + Return
- Right-Command + Shift + "+"

**Troubleshooting**

I tried fast-user switching. It fails on a brand new user as well, ruling out a lot of software configuration issues.

I swapped out the keyboard with a wired Apple keyboard. Everything works fine on that one.

I found some pointers about how to factory-reset a Apple Magic Keyboard, but the UI they describe does not appear in my Bluetooth menu.

**Configuration**

Keyboard firmware level 1.6.0.

iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017)

macOS version 12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was indeed a hardware problem. The fix involved digging around in the closet to find a different keyboard.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer.